# Prevent user to access other users' information

Tags: user-information-list

There is many way to access other users' information in SharePoint 2013.

For example:

- Shared With button in Ribbon
- Manage Permission button in Ribbon
- Version view for ListItem

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks :)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? There's rarely a single "best way" of doing things as it often depends on what your needs are in a given situation.

Comment: I want to prevent user to get a list of other users and to access the information of others like email address.

Comment: The user with only readonly permission should not be able to access to user list on the item. This is why I want to accomplish.